# How to grab just the first 3 elements in the table? Selenium Web Driver

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, element

I just want to grab the first 3 `<td>` elements of each row.

So forexample: 'Vanessa 17 Sociology', 'Mike 18 Maths' and 'Sam 18 English'

How do I go about doing this in Selenium using web driver.

```
<table id= "table3">
   <thead> </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="odd"> 
        <td> Vanessa   </td>
        <td> 17 </td>
        <td> Sociology </td>
        <td> Female </td>
        <td> Student </td>
   </tr>
    <tr class="even"> 
        <td> Mike   </td>
        <td> 18 </td>
        <td> Maths </td>
        <td> Male </td>
        <td> Student </td>
   </tr>
    <tr class="odd"> 
        <td> Sam   </td>
        <td> 18 </td>
        <td> English </td>
        <td> Female </td>
        <td> Student </td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

At the moment I only have this:
`var mainStudents = driver.FindElements(By.Id("table3"));`

As expected, this returns the whole table including the `<th>` and all of the `<td>` which I don't want.

Comment: Create a new collection, loop through `mainStudents`, take what you want and add to your new collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I grabbed all of the elements this way and just looped through them with a count to get the result I needed.

```
IList<IWebElement> trList = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//table[@id='table3']//tr//td[position()<4]"));
int count = 0;
foreach (var trElement in trList)
{

    Console.Write(trElement.Text  + " ");
    count++;
    if (count == 3)
    {
        count = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("");

    }
}
```

Comment: Please do necessary C# related syntax correction in case any error

Answer (score 0):

The below xpath will get first 3 columns in each row. You have to get the row count and then iterate through it.

```
//tbody/tr[row_number]/td[position()<4]
```

It would be easy to run the jquery and get your desired output as shown below.

[image]

You can refer to [this](https://github.com/AcklenAvenue/JQSelenium) to know how to run jquery in your Selenium C# program. You can build the jquery string in your script based on the row number and then send it as query something like below.

```
var jqf = new JQueryFactory(driver); //Create the jQueryFactory
# write the loop here
   # with in the loop
   var row_text = jqf.Query("//tbody/tr[row_number]/td[position()<4]");
```